# pdftotext had different versions on linux and windows

Tags: linux, pdf, text-extraction, pdftotext, poppler

I"m using a simple utility called pdftotext to extract text from pdf files. I have found it to have the cleanest and clerest output when using the `-table` option, **but** this command line option is only available on the windows version of the utility. The Linux and Mac-OS versions have all the other features but not `-table`

And I am aware of `-layout` option, which is present in all versions.

**How can I use the `-table` option in `pdftotext` linux?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `-table` option you need to download the command line tools from XpdfReader [website](https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html)

Then just extract the files and copy the executable from either the bin32 or bin64 folder to /usr/local/bin